# SQL count / query assistance

Tags: mysql, sql, count

So I'm learning MySQL and I'm trying to do the following:

For each instructor list his / her name and the number of students he / she mentors.

The relevant part of the schema is:

```
Person(ID, Name)
Student(StudentID, MentorID)
Instructor(InstructorID)
```

Both `InstructorID` and `StudentID` map to `Person.ID`, and `MentorID` maps to `InstructorID` (Each student has an instructor mentor, and both instructors and students are Persons).

I've tried the following to no avail:

```
select p.Name, count(select s.StudentID
                     from Student s
                     where s.MentorID = i.InstructorID)
from Person p, Instructor i
where p.ID = i.InstructorID;
```

Also this after reading some things on StackOverflow:

```
select InstructorDetails.Name, count(Mentees)
from Instructor i
inner join Person as InstructorDetails
    on InstructorDetails.ID = i.InstructorID
inner join Student as Mentees
    on Mentees.MentorID = i.InstructorID;
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You lack `GROUP BY` on your query,

```
SELECT InstructorDetails.Name, count(*) totalCount
FROM   Instructor i
       INNER JOIN Person as InstructorDetails
           ON InstructorDetails.ID = i.InstructorID
       INNER JOIN Student as Mentees
           ON Mentees.MentorID = i.InstructorID
GROUP BY InstructorDetails.Name
```

Comment: Thanks John, this seems like it should work!  However, I'm getting a syntax error (com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.MySQLSyntaxErrorException).  I'm running it through a special app for my class, but can you think of anything that can be wrong?

Comment: you used the alias in the `COUNT`,it should be `COUNT(*)`

Comment: Alright, thanks!  I'm still learning, so thank you for your help :)